# Transformar local em CEP

Tags: r, cep, código-postal

Alguém conhece um script no R, ou poderia me ajudar a montar um, que pegue o nome de um local e busque o CEP deste?

Comment: Por "nome" você quer dizer o nome de um estabelecimento qualquer (tipo "Shopping ABC")? Ou um endereço? Em ambos os casos você terá que implementar sua própria solução, porém o segundo caso é bem mais fácil (já existem web services expondo dados dos correiros).

Comment: Era endereço. Abaixo já me auxiliaram. Obrigado!

Comment: É possível "espacializar o CEP" conforme [demonstrado no "stackoverflow de SIG"](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/43105/7505), permitindo tanto o refinamento espacial de áreas de CEP muito amplas, como a correlação com outros dados espaciais. Usuários de [R em banco de dados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30638/4186) podem explorar amplamente os recursos do Geoprocessamento  e da análise espacial através do [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O Google fornece o CEP em alguns casos e já existem pacotes com funções para acessar a API do google, o [`ggmap` é um deles.](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/index.html)

Por exemplo:

```
library(ggmap)
end <- geocode("Avenida das Americas, 4666 - Barra da Tijuca, Rio de Janeiro", output="more")
end$postal_code
[1] "22640-102"
```

Entretanto você tem que ter em mente que isso usa o Google Maps, que é bastante sensível à forma que você faz a query e não necessariamente vai ter tudo o que você quer pesquisar.

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Era isso mesmo o que eu precisava!

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa à resposta do Carlos é você carregar uma base de CEPs (adquirida) e fazer a busca diretamente nela.

Eu usei o arquivo CSV de exemplo do site [QualOCep](http://www.qualocep.com/base-de-cep/) (não conheço o site, e creio que idealmente deve ser mais garantido comprar esses dados [diretamente dos Correios](http://www.correios.com.br/para-voce/correios-de-a-a-z/e-dne))

```
> cep_data = read.table('cepbr_texto_exemplo.csv', header=TRUE, sep=';')
> query = subset(cep_data, Logradouro=="Max William Silva Gomes")
> cep = query[1]
> query
  CEP Tipo_Logradouro              Logradouro Complemento Local
  1 8382342             Rua Max William Silva Gomes                  
  Bairro     Cidade UF     Estado
  1 Recanto Verde do Sol SÃ£o Paulo SP SÃ£o Paulo
> cep
  1 8382342
```

Comment: Ótima alternativa! Obrigado!