# Estratégias para analisar bases de dados muito grandes em R (que não caibam na memória RAM)

Tags: r, data.frame, memória, big-data

Suponha que eu tenha uma base de dados enorme que não caiba na memória RAM. Quais estratégias para analisar esta base de dados no R, uma vez que não posso carregá-la inteiramente na memória?

PS: a pergunta não trata somente de como fazer o R conversar com uma base de dados relacional/não-relacional. Se, por exemplo, os seus dados estiverem em uma base de dados relacional, você ainda assim não pode carregá-los todos de uma vez no R para rodar um random forest ou uma regressão, por exemplo.

Comment: A pergunta encontrava-se meio aberta, genérica... Após edição ainda ficou um pouco da impressão de que carece de apoio de base de dados, o que deu margem a sugerir o PostreSQL como "solução". Fazer uma regressão linear exige apenas ter os dados em dois vetores e entregá-los a uma função, o que se faz com PL/R... Talvez perguntando "como resolver uma regressão linear em R com PL/R e dados de uma tabela XY?" seja menos aberto.

Comment: @PeterKrauss dê uma olhada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612320/when-running-pl-r-on-postgresql-can-r-handle-data-bigger-then-ram

Comment: Hum... pelo visto você agora achou exatamente o que precisava, dentro do escopo de resposta que eu desejava dar... Mas tivemos um *"... but unfortunately..."* do próprio J. Conway que é "o cara" do PL/R. Uma pena.

Comment: Claramente algo para `data.table`. Sugiro a leitura [desta apresentação](http://user2014.stat.ucla.edu/files/talk_Matt.pdf). O `data.table` permite manusear e analisar tabelas com centenas de milhões de linhas. `fread` lê ficheiros com 20Gb em poucos minutos.

Comment: @PauloCardoso o `data.table` trabalha dentro do `R`, e também está limitado ao que sua memória RAM permitir.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

R é uma linguagem especializada cujo *sweet spot* são problemas de análise de dados em memória (um conjunto extremamente significativo de problemas).

Dito isso o ecossistema do R é grande e diversas soluções estão surgindo para tratar problemas com volumes enormes de dados. Tenha em mente que problemas de *Big Data* utilizam sim técnicas específicas (e muitas vezes, soluções de Software / Hardware / Sistema de Arquivos e protocolos específicos) como [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce). Não assuma que você pode fazer tudo o que faz em uma `data.frame` com volumes de dados gigantescos, e, mesmo que determinada técnica possa ser aplicada, não assuma que os algoritmos são parecidos.

Tenha em mente que assuntos como regressão com MapReduce ainda são problemas de pesquisa em aberto, novos algoritmos e novas implementações estão surgindo dentro e fora do ecossistema R (você pode encontrar mais informações em *papers* como [*Robust Regression on MapReduce*](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/mmahoney/pubs/rrinmr-icml13.pdf)).

Para te dar um gosto sobre por onde começar, já existem pacotes que implementam:

- Estruturas de dados massivas / mapeamento em disco / blocagem como [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html) e [ff](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html).
- Algoritmos para analisar *data sets* demasiadamente grandes para caber em memória (veja por exemplo o [biglm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/index.html) para problemas de regressão linear).
- Soluções baseadas em Hadoop para orquestrar *jobs* `MapReduce` com `R` (veja [MapReduce with R on Hadoop and Amazon EMR](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/mapreduce-r-hadoop-amazon-emr/) e [Revolution Analytics](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/))
- Ecossistemas para HPC como o [pbdR](http://r-pbd.org/) e [Oracle R Enterprise](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/r/r-enterprise/overview/index.html).

Answer (score 20):

Essa pergunta depende de alguns fatores como a tarefa de análise que se deseja realizar e o tamanho do conjunto de dados, isto é, o quanto ele é grande em relação à memória RAM (e as vezes o HD) do computador onde se pretende realizar a análise. Existem alguns casos a se considerar:

Quanto ao tamanho do conjunto de dados:

- Conjuntos de dados maiores que a RAM mas menores que HD's comuns em
  computadores pessoais, algo como 20Gb por exemplo.
- Conjuntos de dados maiores que a RAM e o HD de computadores pessoais.

Quanto ao tipo de análise:

- Análises descritivas, consultas e cálculos simples.
- Análises mais complexas, incluindo ajuste de modelos como RandomForest, Regressões Lineares e etc.

Quando o conjunto de dados é de tamanho moderado, maior que a RAM, mas não tão grande a ponto de que seja impossível tratá-lo em um único PC, pacotes do R como [ff](http://ff.r-forge.r-project.org/), [Bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html) ou mesmo o pacote [ScaleR](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/whitepaper/revolution-r-enterprise-scaler-fast-highly-scalable-r-multiple-processors) da Revolution Analytics são capazes de realizar análises simples e mais complexas. Uma ressalva nestes casos são as situações onde, mesmo com esses pacotes, o procedimento é muito lento em relação à necessidade do usuário. Outra solução menos conhecida é utilizar a biblioteca [MADLib](http://madlib.net/), que estende o Postgres e permite realizar análises complexas em grandes conjuntos de dados, como Regressões Lineares/Logísticas, RandomForest e etc, diretamente a partir do R por meio do pacote [PivotalR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PivotalR/index.html).

Se a análise envolve somente consultas simples e estatísticas descritivas, uma solução interessante pode ser simplesmente carregar o conjunto de dados em um Sistema de Gerenciamento de Banco de Dados (SGBD) como o [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/), o [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), o [SQLite3](http://www.sqlite.org/) e o [MonetDB](https://www.monetdb.org/Downloads), e transformar os cálculos em consultas em SQL. Outra alternativa é utilizar o pacote [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr), com o qual o usuário define a origem dos dados como um destes SGBD's e o pacote converte automaticamente operações do dplyr em código SQL. Além destas alternativas, o dplyr permite a utilização de serviços de Big Data na nuvem, como o [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/), onde o usuário pode realizar operações de consulta diretamente a partir do terminal com o dplyr, da mesma forma que faria caso estivesse utilizando um data.frame.

Em situações onde o conjunto de dados é muito maior que a memória RAM, por vezes intratável em um único computador, há a necessidade de se utilizar *frameworks* que permitem processamento distribuído de grandes conjuntos de dados como o [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) ou o [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/). Nestes casos, dependendo do tipo de análise que se deseja realizar, como consultas e cálculos simples, o Hadoop + R com o pacote [RHadoop](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki) ou o Spark + R com o pacote [SparkR](http://amplab-extras.github.io/SparkR-pkg/) podem ser suficientes.

Tanto o Hadoop quanto o Spark, contam com projetos associados que implementam métodos de Machine Learning como [Apache Mahout](https://mahout.apache.org/) e a [MLib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-guide.html), que não estão disponíveis para o uso junto ao R. Entretanto existe o engine [H2O](http://0xdata.com/) da 0xadata que possui uma API para o [R](http://0xdata.com/blog/2013/08/run-h2o-from-within-r/) tal que o usuário pode implementar métodos de modelagem em grandes conjuntos de dados. A MADlib, citada anteriormente, também pode ser utilizada em sistemas de gerenciamento de banco de dados distribuídos como o [Greenplum](http://www.pivotal.io/big-data/pivotal-greenplum-database), tal que junto ao pacote PivotalR, permite realizar análises complexas. O pacote ScaleR da Revolution também pode ser utilizado nestes casos, onde ele utiliza uma infraestrutura de Big Data como backend.

Comment: +1 muito boa a resposta, Flávio!

Answer (score 3):

Sugiro como solução para lidar com grandes volumes de dados um  [sistema de gerenciamento de banco de dados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados), "arroz com feijão" ([modelo relacional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banco_de_dados_relacional))... Nesse contexto, o melhor *software FOSS* (satisfaz demandas de robustes, estabilidade, escalabilidade, etc.) é o [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/).

Alguns usuários de *R* vem usando o PostgreSQL desde ~2006, portanto já se encontra bem estável e documentado: o [módulo de "R embedded"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/external-pl.html) (*PL/R - R Procedural Language for PostgreSQL*), dá a liberdade de você criar *procedures* de banco de dados com *R* — por exemplo *triggers* de UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE escritas com jargão R ao invés de PL ou outra linguagem estranha — e efetuar praticamente todas as operações de *R* (sobre tipos de dados básicos) nos scripts do próprio banco de dados.

No [SOen tem umas dicas de como  instalar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2932028/287948).

Entretanto, aparentemente o PL/R ainda teria as mesmas restrições de memória RAM que o R, [conforme pode ser visto nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612320/when-running-pl-r-on-postgresql-can-r-handle-data-bigger-then-ram).

Comment: Seria muito interessante citar as fontes das afirmações do primeiro parágrafo.

Comment: Peter, para complementar, como você rodaria um modelo de random forest ou uma regressão, sem pode acessar todos os dados ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Prezados, a intensão do primeiro parágrafo foi "puxar sardinha" para o uso de "base de dados com R" e para o uso do PostgreSQL... Ficou um texto meio marketeiro, concordo, mesmo assim, sem tempo de lapidar, já respondi abrindo para Wiki... Não entendi   porque do ''downvote''. Sugerem DELETAR A RESPOSTA?

Comment: @CarlosCinelli, entendo que o modelo relacional tem limitações, tanto que dados complexos como no PostGIS (geometrias) usam  o banco relacional apenas como alternativa ao *filesystem*, não para "fazer as contas". Pode-se [armazenar estruturas complexas em sua representação binária](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-binary.html), resolvendo ao menos o problema da gestão de dados com isso. A vantagem de uso do banco com R  se faz mais nítida na geração automática de relatórios, e quando existe grande diversidade de dados simples relacionados.

Comment: @gmsantos, os links são as fontes. Tamnbém fiz edições para ficar menos marketeiro, aguardo sua nova posição.

Comment: @PeterKrauss a resposta em si é totalmente marketeira. A única sugestão valiosa é a citação do modulo de PL/R do Postgre, que na pergunta não é exemplificado seu uso, sugerido uma implementação ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Peter, faltaria complementar com a parte de como analisar os dados, rodar modelos preditivos por exemplo, com a restrição de não poder carregar tudo de uma vez dentro do R.

Comment: Peter, aparentemente o PL/R não resolve o problema de limitação da memória RAM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612320/when-running-pl-r-on-postgresql-can-r-handle-data-bigger-then-ram .

Comment: @CarlosCinelli, sim, como comentei acima (na pergunta) o próprio J. Conway já deu seu veredicto. PS: se matematicamente o problema for "refatorável" (em geral não sem perda de exatidão), o SQL ajuda a fragmentar e depois juntar/sumarizar os resultados parciais.

Answer (score 3):

Sempre existe a opção de trabalhar com bancos externos ao R e carregar somente as variáveis necessárias para a análise (uma vez que são raras as análises que usarão todas as variáveis ao mesmo tempo). Existem vários pacotes que permitem trabalhar com outros tipos de bancos, dos quais destaco [RSQLite](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html). Ele possui funções que criam bancos de dados SQLite de arquivos com delimitadores e sem (de largura fixa).