# Como ler os microdados do ENEM no R?

Tags: r, csv, big-data

O INEP (Instituto Nacional de Estudos e Pesquisas Educacionais Anísio Teixeira) disponibiliza para download os microdados do ENEM (e outros) a partir deste [link](http://portal.inep.gov.br/basica-levantamentos-acessar). Estes microdados são os dados crús do ENEM, com informações na granularidade de alunos.

Ao fazer o download dos microdados do [ENEM 2014](http://download.inep.gov.br/microdados/microdados_enem2014.zip), por exemplo, você baixa um arquivo com extensão zip de aproximadamente 1,2Gb. Ao extrair o conteúdo deste arquivo há na estrutura de pastas toda a documentação deste conjunto de dados e também os microdados. Na pasta DADOS há o arquivo MICRODADOS_ENEM_2014.csv. Esse arquivo tem 6Gb de tamanho tal que comandos como:

```
dados <- read.csv('MICRODADOS_ENEM_2014.csv', header=T)
```

não funcionam na maioria dos PC's comuns em virtude da limitação da memória RAM.

Qual é a melhor alternativa para ler este conjunto de dados no R em um PC comum? Gostaria especialmente de métodos concretos para efetuar esta leitura com a ajuda de pacotes do R e TAMBÉM utilizando sistemas de gerenciamento de banco de dados.

OBS: Estou ciente com relação a pergunta [Estratégias para analisar bases de dados muito grandes em R (que não caibam na memória RAM)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30631/estrat%C3%A9gias-para-analisar-bases-de-dados-muito-grandes-em-r-que-n%C3%A3o-caibam-na-m), tendo inclusive participado como um dos respondentes. ENTRETANTO, a pergunta teve um caráter mais genérico, não produzindo nas respostas nenhum código em R que pudesse resolver o problema específico desta questão.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Estratégias para analisar bases de dados muito grandes em R (que não caibam na memória RAM)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30631/estrat%c3%a9gias-para-analisar-bases-de-dados-muito-grandes-em-r-que-n%c3%a3o-caibam-na-m)

Comment: @Molx eu fui uma das pessoas que respondeu essa questão. Aquela era uma questão mais conceitual, com um caráter mais aberto. Esta em especial é bem mais específica e relacionada a um conjunto de dados em específico. Como resultado dessa questão também ficará documentado o código em R necessário para realizar essa tarefa. Muita gente vai no google especificamente para procurar uma solução para esse problema.

Comment: Também não acho que seja duplicata.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli acho que o pessoal quando ganha acesso a fila de análise nem lê direito a questão e já começa a querer "agir". Basta ler com calma para perceber que são questões diferentes.

Comment: Usar o Hadoop e o MapReduce, afim de filtrar e reduzir a quantidade de dados, seria uma opcao que lhe ajuda ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Conceitos

Foram ótimas respostas até agora mas vou acrescentar aqui meus dois centavos. Eu diria que quando estamos trabalhando com conjuntos de dados que superam bastante o tamanho da memória RAM, para mim, o ideal é sempre trabalhar com sistemas de gerenciamento de banco de dados, como o PostgreSQL, o MySQL ou o MonetDB. Especialmente com microdados públicos, que em geral você só precisa ler uma vez e a partir daí só consultar, acredito que os SGBDs são a melhor abordagem. Além de permitir o armazenamento consistente dos dados, também é possível utilizar o pacote dplyr no R, com o [backend de bancos de dados](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html), tal que você pode utilizar as tabelas do banco utilizando praticamente a mesma sintaxe que utilizaria com um data.frame. É uma solução que é rápida, não tem as limitações que o R têm com RAM e que você pode utilizar depois por muito tempo.

Dos SGBDs disponíveis, dois que não dão nenhum trabalho de usar com R, não precisando ter que instalar nenhum outro software além do prórprio R são:

- [SQLite3](https://www.sqlite.org/);
- [MonetDB](https://www.monetdb.org/Home);

O primeiro pode ser utilizado facilmente a partir do R por meio do pacote [RSQlite](https://cran.r-project.org/) e o segundo por meio do pacote [MonetDBLite](https://cran.r-project.org/). O meu preferido, e o que eu vou utilizar aqui como exemplo, é o MonetDB. Vou utilizá-lo porque dos dois é aquele que faz o armazenamento por [colunas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS). ASSIM, a operação de escrita é um pouco mais cara, mas qualquer operação de consulta é muito mais barata. Se você trabalha com dados que não precisam ser escritos com frequência, mas precisam ser lidos com frequência, sistemas de gerenciamento de banco de dados colunares são superiores. Por outro lado, se além de ler você também precisa escrever no banco frequentemente, um banco como o SQLite (e outros) deve ser superior. Especificamente no caso de microdados, como Censo, ENEM ou Censo Escolar, que você deve carregar o banco uma vez e somente ler a partir daí, acredito que o MonetDB é a melhor opção disponível hoje.

### Aplicação

Para utilizar a solução que vou propor aqui você deve ter o pacote MonetDBLite instalado no seu computador. No console do R digite:

```
install.packages('MonetDBLite', dependencies = TRUE)
```

A partir daí, o próximo passo será carregar os dados no banco. Felizmente o MonetDBLite é um pacote que permite fazer isso de forma automática utilizando a função monetdb.read.csv(). Supondo que você está com o conjunto de dados do ENEM, no meu caso o microdados_enem2014.csv, no mesmo diretório de trabalho onde você vai rodar o script, execute os seguintes comandos:

```
## Carregando os pacotes necessários
library(MonetDBLite)
library(DBI)

## Definindo um diretório
dbdir <- 'database/'

## Criando a conexão com um banco, criado na pasta database
con <- dbConnect( MonetDBLite::MonetDBLite() , dbdir )

## Fazendo a ingestao do csv no banco
monetdb.read.csv(conn = con, files = 'microdados_enem2014.csv', tablename = 'enem2014', header = TRUE, na.strings = '', delim = ',')

## Listando as tabelas no banco
dbListTables(con)

## Contanto o número de registros no banco
dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT count(*) FROM enem2014')

## Consultando as 100 primeiras linhas
teste <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM enem2014 LIMIT 100")
```

O carregamento não demorou nem um minuto aqui na minha máquina, core i5 e 16Gb de RAM. Mas acredito que em uma máquina mais modesta deve demorar um pouco mais. Outro ponto fundamental é que o ideal é que o arquivo esteja em UTF-8 para o carregamento, e os csv's do ENEM estão em ISO-8859-1. Eu converti o arquivo facilmente por meio do comando iconv no terminal do Linux:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 MICRODADOS_ENEM_2014.csv > microdados_enem2014.csv
```

mas no Windows você deve seguir o procedimento de instalação do iconv mostrado [aqui](https://dbaportal.eu/2012/10/24/iconv-for-windows/). De fato há várias maneiras de mudar a codificação de arquivos no Windows e essa é somente uma sugestão.

Outro ponto a salientar é que como o banco e a tabela no banco já foram criados, você pode fazer consultas diretamente em SQL, como se estivesse no terminal do banco. Se você souber SQL seu problema está resolvido e basta gerar os dados necessários a partir da consulta e depois processá-los como data.frame no R.

### Usando o dplyr

Naturalmente a melhor opção para usar bancos de dados com o R é utilizando o dplyr diretamente, o que permite ao usuário do R trabalhar com o banco sem escrever uma única linha de SQL. O mais legal dessa estratégia é que o dplyr converte os comandos em R para querys em SQL e até os resultados intermediários das consultas ficam dentro do banco de dados, tal que não há problemas de performance relacionados as limitações do R com a memória RAM.

Como um exemplo, vamos consultar a nota média dos alunos por estado e dependência administrativa, usando o dplyr.

```
## Carregando o pacote
library(dplyr)

## Ligando o dplyr na tabela
my_db <- MonetDBLite::src_monetdb(embedded=dbdir)
my_tbl <- tbl(my_db, "enem2014")

## Obtendo média de matemática por estado e dependência administrativa
consulta <- my_tbl %>% group_by(COD_UF_ESC, ID_DEPENDENCIA_ADM_ESC) %>% summarise(mean(NOTA_MT))

## Salvando a consulta como um data.frame
consulta <- collect(consulta)
```

o que resulta em:

```
  COD_UF_ESC ID_DEPENDENCIA_ADM_ESC       L1
        <int>                  <int>    <dbl>
1          NA                     NA 472.1223
2          26                      2 441.0514
3          32                      2 454.2741
4          35                      2 468.1310
5          11                      2 440.4378
6          33                      4 554.1954
7          33                      2 456.5003
8          23                      2 436.1984
9          29                      2 433.5961
10         53                      4 447.5004
```

Veja que será necessário converter os códigos das Unidades da Federação e da dependência administrativa para os respectivos nomes, que estão disponíveis no dicionário que vem com os dados do ENEM. Outro ponto é que ao final da consulta, para "salvar" o resultado da consulta como um data.frame no R você deve usar a função collect().

Por fim, ao terminar de utilizar o banco, você pode desconectar e desligar a instância do MonetDB que foi criada e está rodando na sua máquina:

```
## Desconectando do banco
dbDisconnect(con, shutdown=TRUE)
```

fique tranquilo que seus dados estão intactos. Se você precisar usar o banco depois basta reconectar como já fizemos anteriormente:

```
## Criando a conexão com um banco, criado na pasta database
con <- dbConnect( MonetDBLite::MonetDBLite() , dbdir )
```

Answer (score 13):

As funções do tipo `read.csv` que o `R` possui carregam na memória RAM o conteúdo dos arquivos que estão sendo lidos. Assim, há três maneiras principais de se trabalhar com dados grandes que não cabem na memória do `R`:

1. Aumente a sua memória RAM
2. Tome uma amostra dos seus dados
3. Leia os dados a partir do disco, sem carregá-los na RAM

A solução 1 seria a ideal. Afinal, não seria preciso aprender nada novo, pois poderíamos trabalhar com os dados carregados diretamente na RAM, como se fosse um arquivo de tamanho normal. Entretanto, isto custa dinheiro.

A solução 2 não é ruim. Desde que se tome uma amostra representativa dos dados, não há porque imaginar que a análise feita deste jeito seja ruim. Mas nós estatísticos já trabalhamos com amostragem por tanto tempo. Por que não aproveitamos esta infinidade de dados que temos hoje em dia e não analisamos todos eles? Afinal, melhor do que cometer pequenos erros ao analisar uma amostra é não cometer erro nenhum, analisando a população inteira.

A solução 3 é a que mais me agrada. Ela implica em não carregar completamente os dados na memória RAM, e sim lê-los de maneira incremental a partir do disco. Felizmente, o `R` possui diversos pacotes que facilitam a nossa vida para fazer isto. Eu vou utilizar um deles aqui, chamado `ff`.

No exemplo abaixo eu carrego o pacote `ff`, leio os microdados do ENEM do ano de 2014 e crio uma tabela com o número de candidatos inscritos por estado brasileiro:

```
library(ff)
enem <- read.csv.ffdf(file="MICRODADOS_ENEM_2014.csv", header=TRUE)
table(enem[, 22])
             AC      AL      AM      AP      BA      CE      DF 
  70096   65269  156393  172709   45553  720330  572238  143196 
     ES      GO      MA      MG      MS      MT      PA      PB 
 149299  218662  354018  987173  152758  155066  459417  233768 
     PE      PI      PR      RJ      RN      RO      RR      RS 
 441963  214878  409248  589757  196980   97263   19064  478792 
     SC      SE      SP      TO 
 143680  117885 1289458   67335
```

Note que utilizei o mesmo comando `table` que utilizamos normalmente para criar uma tabela de contagens no `R`. A única diferença está no comando `read.csv.ffdf`, que tem sintaxe idêntica do `read.csv` neste caso. Aliás, mesmo em outros casos, a sintaxe do `read.csv.ffdf` é bastante similar à sintaxe do `read.csv`.

Claro que esta solução tem problemas. O principal deles é a velocidade. Eu avaliei o tempo de execução dos dois comandos acima no meu PC e obtive o seguinte:

```
system.time(enem <- read.csv.ffdf(file="MICRODADOS_ENEM_2014.csv",
  header=TRUE))
    user   system  elapsed 
3302.942  170.418 3596.523 

system.time(table(enem[, 22]))
 user  system elapsed 
0.550   0.185   0.945
```

Eu levei praticamente uma hora para ler os dados de um ano de ENEM. Só para título de comparação, fiz esta leitura em um laptop Intel i5 2.8GHz com 8GB de RAM e 512GB de SSD. A tabela, entretanto, foi feita bem rapidamente, levando menos de um segundo para ficar pronta.

Portanto, esta é uma maneira de ler grandes conjuntos de dados no `R`. Além do `ff`, o pacote `bigmemory` também é capaz disso. Imagino que hajam ainda mais pacotes, mas minha experiência se limita a estes dois.

---

Saindo um pouco do `R`, o que eu sugiro para ti, a fim de diminuir o tempo gasto na análise, é definir exatamente o que te interessa neste conjunto de dados. Ele tem 166 colunas. É muita coluna. Além disso, ele também tem 8.722.249 linhas. É muita linha. Claro que todas elas são importantes em nível nacional, mas talvez não sejam importantes para ti ou para a análise que tu pretende fazer. Eu recomendo fortemente aprender alguns comandos do `bash`, como `grep`, `cut` e `awk`, para fazer uma pré-filtragem destes dados.

Por exemplo, não há porque ler os resultados de todos os estados brasileiros na memória do `R` se apenas o Rio Grande do Sul te interessa. Talvez importar a chave de respostas de todos os alunos, com as colunas `TX_RESPOSTAS_CN`, `TX_RESPOSTAS_CH`, `TX_RESPOSTAS_LC` e`TX_RESPOSTAS_MT`, não seja interessante para ti. Pode ser ainda que todas as 76 colunas do questionário socioeconônico não importem para a tua análise. Não sei.

Mas, pela minha experiência, sugiro cortar tudo o que não te interessa antes de importar este conjunto de dados no R para poder facilitar a tua análise, principalmente se teu interesse for analisar os resultados de mais de um ano do ENEM. Imagine o tempo que vai ser gasto se tu precisar combinar os resultados de quase 20 anos do exame. Só a leitura dos dados vai levar 20 horas, assumindo que o tempo de leitura aumente de maneira linear, o que é uma suposição que não faz muito sentido.

Enfim, se eu estivesse fazendo uma análise deste tipo, eu excluiria as colunas e linhas que não me interessam, pois assim eu otimizaria meu código, fazendo com que ele executasse mais rapidamente, pois estaria tendo que gerenciar apenas os dados com os quais eu realmente me importo.

Comment: Bela resposta! Eu acho essencial também verificar a questão das colunas que são necessárias, o tamanho dos arquivos pode ser reduzido a ponto de que a leitura com `read.csv` se torne trivial.

Answer (score 7):

Uma solução elegante e que pode ser praticamente independente de recursos computacionais é utilizar um software de pré-processamento linha a linha, filtrando apenas os registros desejados. A ferramenta mais conhecida e popular para esse tipo de tarefa é a [AWK](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) - uma linguagem de manipulação de textos -, cuja principal implementação é [o gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/). O gawk possui implentações para Linux, Windows e MacOS.

Não tenho exatamente os dados do ENEM, mas suponha que você queira processar os arquivos do Censo Escolar 2015 (que, imagino, são bem semelhantes). A tabela TURMAS.CSV contém dados de todas as turmas de educação básica regular no Brasil. Há um campo nesta tabela, cujo cabeçalho indica o nome "CO_UF", que é o código da unidade da federação. Para filtrar somente os registros do Espírito Santo, por exemplo, cujo código de unidade da federação é 32 (conforme IBGE), eu chamaria o gawk da seguinte maneira:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FS="|"} { if($73 == 32) print $0 }' TURMAS.CSV
```

Primeiramente (BEGIN) eu declaro o field separator (FS) como "|", que é o separador usado nestes arquivos do INEP. Depois eu verifico se o campo 73 (esta parte é chata, eu preciso contar os campos na descrição do CSV, ou na primeira linha que é o cabeçalho) é igual a 32 (código do ES). No gawk cada campo, divido pelo separador, é ordenado e identificado após o cifrão ($).

Se o teste for positivo, eu imprimo a linha inteira (o código $0 é especial e imprime toda a linha "recomposta", ou seja, os campos e os separadores). Para fazer uso desse filtro, eu redireciono o pipe para um arquivo:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FS="|"} { if($73 == 32) print $0 }' TURMAS.CSV > filtrado_es.csv
```

O arquivo filtrado_es.csv contém, então, somente os registros que satisfizeram a condição de código de UF igual a 32, e portanto será menor, fazendo sofrer menos o R!

Se você tiver o gawk no seu PATH, pode chamar ele dentro do próprio R através do comando pipe(). Por exemplo:

```
read.csv(pipe("gawk 'BEGIN {FS=\"|\"} {if ($73 == 32) print $0}'
/caminho/para/TURMAS.CSV"))
```

Neste caso, o read.csv irá ler o arquivo já pré-processado pelo gawk.

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução muito boa é usar a função read_csv_chunked() do pacote readr. Esta função permite a leitura e aplicação de uma função a cada chunk (número de linhas) iterativamente. Suponha que você quer apenas os dados do estado de São Paulo. Você pode limitar o número de linhas para importar de cada vez e filtrá-las por UF=="SP", antes de proceder ao seguinte chunk. Para tanto, basta  seguir o seguinte procedimento:

```
f<-function(x,pos) subset(x,UF=="SP")

df<-readr::read_csv_chunked("MICRODADOS_ENEM_2014.csv",DataFrameCallback$new(f),
chunk_size = 1000)
```