# Como calcular a mediana quando os dados estão em chunks?

Tags: r, algoritmo

Suponha que os meus dados estão divididos em 2 vetores:

```
x <- c(100, 400, 120)
y <- c(500, 112)
```

Eu poderia calcular a mediana, juntando os dois vetores e depois usando a função `median`.

```
median(c(x,y))
[1] 120
```

Suponha que por um motivo não consigo carregar todos os meus dados de uma só vez na memória RAM, por isso não consigo combinar os dois vetores para depois calcular a mediana.

Se eu fosse calcular a média, dessa forma, em chunks, eu poderia fazer o seguinte:

- Calculo a soma e o numero de elementos de `x`
- Calculo a soma e o número de elementos de `y`
- Somo a soma de x com a soma de y e o numero de elementos de x com o número de elementos de y
- Divido um pelo outro, exemplo:

Exemplo:

```
x_sum <- sum(x)
x_l <- length(x)
y_sum <- sum(y)
y_l <- length(y)
(x_sum + y_sum)/(x_l + y_l)
[1] 246.4
```

Isso me permitiria calcular a média sem em nenhum momento precisar possuir os dois vetores carregados na memória RAM.

Qual algoritmo eu poderia utilizar para fazer algo parecido, mas para calcular a mediana?

**Obs** Usei a linguagem R para os exemplos, mas a resposta não precisa estar em R, desde que explique o algoritmo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Minha intuição diz que este problema não tem uma solução exata como no caso da média. Pensando num caso simples, com duas amostras `x` e `y`, onde

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1)
y <- c(1, 2, 3)
```

Temos que

```
median(c(x, y))
[1] 1
```

Mas se tentarmos fazer a média das medianas ou a mediana das medianas, obtemos valores diferentes do valor procurado:

```
mean(c(median(x), median(y)))
[1] 1.5
median(c(median(x), median(y)))
[1] 1.5
```

Isto se deve ao fato da mediana jogar informação fora, ainda mais informação do que a média joga. Por exemplo, o tamanho amostral não é importante para calcular a mediana. A única coisa que importa é saber se o tamanho amostral é par ou ímpar.

Por isso, volto à minha afirmação inicial. Minha intuição diz que este problema não tem uma solução **exata**, mas nada nos impede de encontrar uma solução **aproximada**.

Já ouviu falar em [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics))? É uma técnica estatística que permite encontrar a distribuição amostral de qualquer estatística sobre a qual não temos maiores informações.

A ideia básica é pegar uma amostra de tamanho *n = x_l + y_l*, com reposição, dos dois vetores que tu tem, e calcular a mediana de cada uma delas. Repita este procedimento milhares de vezes. Com isto, tu vai ter a distribuição amostral da mediana da tua população de interesse. Aí vai ser possível calcular a média ou a mediana destas amostras. [Este link tem uma aplicação bem bacana deste conceito](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat464/node/80). Eu escrevi um pequeno código que faz isto, sem utilizar o pacote `boot` do `R`. Neste código eu tomo amostras de tamanho 10, que podem ter tamanho `x_l` de 0 a 10 para o vetor `x` e tamanho `n-x_l` para o vetor `y`. Eu repito este procedimento 10 mil vezes. No final, tomo a média destas simulações como sendo o valor da mediana de `c(x,y)`:

```
n           <- 10
repl        <- 100000
median_boot <- 0

for (i in 1:repl){
    x_l <- sample(0:n, 1)
    y_l <- n-x_l

    x_sample <- sample(x, x_l, replace=TRUE)
    y_sample <- sample(y, y_l, replace=TRUE)

    median_boot[i] <- median(c(x_sample, y_sample))
}

mean(median_boot)
1.29458

median(median_boot)
1

sd(median_boot)
0.4767598

hist(median_boot)
```

[image: histograma]

Note que a média `1.29458` ficou distante do valor real da mediana, que é `1`. Entretanto, ficou muito melhor do que o valor `1.5` que estimei anteriormente, de maneira ingênua. Isto ocorre porque os dados que utilizei são bastante mal comportados. Estes resultados devem ficar bem melhores se tu tiver uma distribuição "melhor" comportada, com mais dados, mas não necessariamente simétrica em relação à média.

Além disso, é possível, com o vetor `median_boot`, criar um intervalo de confiança empírico para a mediana. No caso, basta pegar os percentis a 2,5% e 97,5% para encontrá-lo:

```
c(quantile(median_boot, 0.025), quantile(median_boot, 0.975))
 2.5% 97.5% 
  1.0   2.5
```

Novamente, o resultado não ficou muito bom porque a distribuição que utilizei não é boa. Os resultados ficarão mais adequados se tu trabalhar com uma distribuição com comportamento melhor, não algo degenerado como este exemplo.

---

[Tu chegou a tentar usar artifícios do R que permitem carregar bases de dados bem grandes na memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154724/como-ler-os-microdados-do-enem-no-r)? Será que algo assim talvez ajude a resolver o teu problema, já que os dados não seriam carregados completamente na memória RAM?

Comment: o bootsatrap assume alguma coisa a respeito dos vetores? Por exemplo, os inivíduos estão distribuidos aleatoriamente entre eles?

Comment: Sim, o bootstrap assume algumas hipóteses. Como é um método de reamostragem, ele assume que o vetor onde as reamostragens são realizadas seja uma amostra representativa da população de interesse. No teu caso, tanto faz o que `x` e `y` sejam, desde que `c(x, y)` seja uma amostra representativa da população.